# EF 6 - can not use string in filter when querying

Tags: entity-framework-6

I just upgraded an asp.net project from EF5 to EF6. This brought a lot of changes to code that needed to be done and I did (changing namespaces and things like that).

Using EF5 I used this form of querying frequently:

var query = mycontext.mytable.Where("my filter").Select(x => x);

Now, using EF6 I can't find a way to use a string in my Where clause. I always get this error for code like this:

***System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Where(System.Linq.IQueryable, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' has some invalid arguments***

Many thanks in advance and bye ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems the answer to this issue is using ObjectQuery from ObjectContext. However, this seems a little confusing to me. It seems this type of query (var q = ctx.Employees.Where(string)) has always been ObjectQueries, but before EF6 you could do that from your normal context. Now you have to create those queries from ObjectContext.

We can have an ObjectContext from our normal context (dbContext) if your issue:

```
var objectContext = (context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
```

then, you can have your ObjectQuery from that context.

It seems EF6 have changed several things, sure to bring better results to everyone. I'm currently in the process of learning those changes and additions.

Many thanks and bye ...

Comment: `DbContext` has become the default API since EF 5.